# How to remove additional white space in between reports data Jasper HTML view only?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing an issue in JasperReports HTML view. While generating the HTML view, it is showing an additional white space in between reports data (see the screenshot bellow). Actually, that extra white space is the report's footer (eg:- pdf page footer), and I don't want  to show this footer in my HTML view. So, I have hidden the footer part altogether.

Is it possible to remove this white space only from the HTML view?

[image: Its reports Html view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved . When I set the parameter `ignore pagination` to `true` on REST API for HTML side only.